# Keep btmgt le always on

Tags: bluetooth

Every time I start my system I need to do `sudo btmgmt le on` to be able to connect my bluetooth keyboard. I was wondering if there is a way to keep this setting always on.

Comment: I'd like to understand why instead of answering the question, people keeps voting it down...

Comment: You could always add a oneshot systemd system service. Also look if you disabled LE by setting `ControllerMode` != `dual` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Keep LE on

Make sure that you didn't set `ControllerMode = bredr` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. If you did, remove that line or set it back to `dual`. Look for other places you might have changed the setting because LE is supposed to be enabled by default.

#### Solution 2: Startup service

1. Paste the following into `/etc/systemd/system/btmgmt-le-askubuntu-1503263-1004020.service` :

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Keep btmgt le always on
After=bluetooth.service

[Service]
# This already runs as root/sudo by default
ExecStart=/usr/bin/btmgmt le on
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Run `sudo systemctl enable btmgmt-le-askubuntu-1503263-1004020.service`
4. Reboot, and observe that this runs your command on every boot

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know why `ControllerMode` was set to `bredr`. Changing it to `dual` made it